# How to end the while loop with either player1 or player2 entering "Q"?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am stuck at a part where in a game, I use while loop and to end the loop and get the results of the game, I want either "player1" or "player2" to enter "Q", and so i tried doing it like this:

```
if (player1.equals("Q") || player2.equals("Q")){
    go = false; //go is a boolean variable 
}
```

This doesn't seem to work as I have to enter "Q" for both player1 and player2 for the game to end, but instead I just want **either** of them to enter "Q" and the game would stop.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Team {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Soccer Game Between 2 Teams");
        System.out.println("Win is 2 points" + "\n" + "Loss is worth 0 points" + "\n" + "Overtime is worth 1 point");
        System.out.println("Type W, O, or L" + "\n" + "Type Q to end the game");
        int pointsw = 0;
        int pointsl = 0;
        int pointso = 0;
        int pointsw2 = 0;
        int pointsl2 = 0;
        int pointso2 = 0;
        int totalpoints = 0;
        int totalpoints2 = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        boolean go = true;
        System.out.println("\n" + "Enter team one:");
        String phrase = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("\n" + "Enter team two:");
        String phrase2 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println();
        while (go) {
            System.out.println("Enter " + phrase + " Result:");
            String team1 = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter " + phrase2 + " Result");
            String team2 = keyboard.next();
            if (team1.equals("W") || team1.equals("w")) {
                pointsw += 2;
            } else if (team1.equals("O") || team1.equals("o")) {
                pointso += 1;
            } else if (team1.equals("L") || team1.equals("l")) {
                pointsl += 0;
            }
            counter++;
            if (team2.equals("W") || team2.equals("w")) {
                pointsw2 += 2;
            } else if (team2.equals("O") || team2.equals("o")) {
                pointso2 += 1;
            } else if (team2.equals("L") || team2.equals("l")) {
                pointsl2 += 0;
            }
            counter2++;
            totalpoints = pointsw + pointso + pointsl;
            totalpoints2 = pointsw2 + pointso2 + pointsl2;
            if (team1.equals("Q") || team2.equals("Q")) {
                go = false;
                if (totalpoints > totalpoints2) {
                    System.out.println(phrase + " wins with " + totalpoints + " points");
                    System.out.println("It took " + phrase + " " + counter + " rounds to win");
                } else if (totalpoints < totalpoints2) {
                    System.out.println(phrase2 + " wins with " + totalpoints2 + " points");
                    System.out.println("It took " + phrase2 + " " + counter2 + " rounds to win");
                } else if (totalpoints == totalpoints2) {
                    int totalrounds = counter + counter2;
                    System.out.println("It is tie game between " + phrase + " and " + phrase2);
                    System.out.println("The game lasted till " + totalrounds + " rounds");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reorganize your code:

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter " + phrase + " Result:");
        String team1 = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
        if ("q".equals(team1)) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter " + phrase2 + " Result");
        String team2 = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
        if ("q".equals(team2)) {
            break;
        }
        if (team1.equals("w")) {
            pointsw += 2;
        } else if (team1.equals("o")) {
            pointso += 1;
        } else if (team1.equals("l")) {
                pointsl += 0;
        }
        counter++;
        if (team2.equals("w")) {
            pointsw2 += 2;
        } else if (team2.equals("o")) {
            pointso2 += 1;
        } else if (team2.equals("l")) {
            pointsl2 += 0;
        }
        counter2++;
        totalpoints = pointsw + pointso + pointsl;
        totalpoints2 = pointsw2 + pointso2 + pointsl2;
    } // loop completed

    if (totalpoints > totalpoints2) {
        System.out.println(phrase + " wins with " + totalpoints + " points");
        System.out.println("It took " + phrase + " " + counter + " rounds to win");
    } else if (totalpoints < totalpoints2) {
        System.out.println(phrase2 + " wins with " + totalpoints2 + " points");
        System.out.println("It took " + phrase2 + " " + counter2 + " rounds to win");
    } else if (totalpoints == totalpoints2) {
        int totalrounds = counter + counter2;
        System.out.println("It is tie game between " + phrase + " and " + phrase2);
        System.out.println("The game lasted till " + totalrounds + " rounds");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I think the issue is that after player 1 / player 2 says 'Q'
the scanner is still waiting for the next line to read.

```
        String phrase = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("\n"+"Enter team two:");
        String phrase2 = keyboard.next();//if player 1 types q this next() method must be resolved before it will continue to the logic
```

so add an if statement before play 2 goes asking if player 1 typed 'Q'  ,  if so calculate scores and end game,  if player 1 did not type 'Q' use else statement to continue on to player 2's turn